# What are 'units' in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2, terminology

I read sites about Dota 2, and there they often mention 'units'. I'm confused because 'units' here doesn't mean 'distance units', but can mean many things. So, could you explain what the term refers to in Dota 2?

Answer (score 6):

A unit is any entity that can be selected and is not a building or a ward. Creeps are units, heroes are units, summons are units, illusions are units.

Note that this definition is not specific to Dota 2, and is used by the vast majority of RTS games.

Comment: do the illusions (or whatever) created by TB's reflection skill count as units?

Comment: @Numi Yes, but they are untargetable like Dark Willow in Shadow Realm, invulnerable, and uncontrollable.

Comment: would they count towards ES' echoslam unit count?

Comment: @Numi As they are invulnerable, most likely not, but I've never tested this specific interaction. You'd probably get a better answer if you asked this question as its own post. It should be fairly easy to test in demo mode, and you can then post your findings as an answer, if you wish.